# How do you seal travertine floors?

Tags: flooring, tile, travertine

I moved into a house with travertine floors. They appear to have been sealed and polished. I recently learned that travertine is highly porous. I recently noticed this tile where the seal appears to have worn away and the stone is "powdering." (No idea if that's the correct term.) What do I use to repair and/or seal this?

[image]

Comment: It also might not be a bad idea to re-apply a coat of sealer every few years. Check the bottle for exactly when to do this. If the shine ever fades from the floor rent a buffer and use a white polishing pad on it. It will shine just like new!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Travertine can have many impurities, and being a sedimentary rock, could have a nugget of softer material.

In any case, use a stiff nylon brush and remove the chalky area.

Rinse the area and note if water absorbs in the nugget area..
If so, good; grout and/or sealer will attach securely.

I would recommend a bit of matching grout in the divot, followed by a penetrating stone sealer.(I prefer Miracle products, but others are fine).

Comment: This makes a beautiful floor but it does come with some maintenance. Your answer is spot on +1.